# Differences between Webcrypto (js) and Cryptodome.Cipher.AES (python)

Tags: aes, block-cipher, aes-gcm, key-size

I'm trying to understand the difference in output of AES decrypt (GCM mode) using Webcrypto and Cryptodome.Cipher.AES in python.

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
key = 'E52BC6CEDC2E096584B1F57D3AE6A60724C7B301EECB975813819673E6D23126'
iv = 'B5DDEDB80480A649D1763BE7'
encrypted_data = '37631B44E6B7DB7C404F2947F40FC629BB537BF303B728A674280C23528C3B09815BA2CD39B3844A38C4527464353A66'
cipher_item_key = AES.new(unhexlify(key), AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=unhexlify(iv))
res = cipher_item_key.decrypt(unhexlify(encrypted_data))
print hexlify(res).upper()
```

prints `EEE72939E910F74104846B5BADBDDAD007A46E3392ADE713F6EE33900299C250C83D25005D7D7E27211B2BBFF48E62AC`

vs

https://gist.github.com/syst3mw0rm/9b22a1eadd6cbf38474573d54cd54f0c

prints `EEE72939E910F74104846B5BADBDDAD007A46E3392ADE713F6EE33900299C250`

I noticed that the first 64 characters as exactly same and that makes me think that the issue is probably with unpadding of output in python but I'm not sure what's the right way to go about doing it or is that is the root cause in the first place.

---

Similarly, I'm noticing a difference in output when encrypting data.

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
key = 'EEE72939E910F74104846B5BADBDDAD007A46E3392ADE713F6EE33900299C250'
iv = '523AEBE425EA83DCE42F9512'
data = '{"username":"test","password":"test"}'
cipher_data = AES.new(unhexlify(key), AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=unhexlify(iv))
cipher_data.update('')
encrypted_data, mac = cipher_data.encrypt_and_digest(bytearray(data))
print (hexlify(encrypted_data) + hexlify(mac)).upper()
```

prints `C7D1A799120CBDD6539378509AFC4D0C3F78BA8D42C9F3546E15DFBD94CBE789350DD3554AF092A39AF0345623E117D28F493CD7DE`

vs

https://gist.github.com/syst3mw0rm/22bb4a8c7c51516b358b482b3336d927

prints `C7F3F0EA027EA0B75BF6286AD688497F265AF3AF10A8BA273B7AD9D9D3F1B6FD247E85771BAE4447F81447389A84A3145155E7DE387D6B3E181516707731EC2DC3CEF847FCA949EE484B3FC0A6C66853D42C956BA0735642D29E`

I'm not sure why the output of above two would be any different. I'm using exact same key, iv, additionalData (defaults to '' according to subtle crypto spec), data. Can someone please tell me if I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: AES-GCM -- https://gist.github.com/syst3mw0rm/9b22a1eadd6cbf38474573d54cd54f0c#file-gistfile1-txt-L93

Comment: I'm actually trying to decrypt. The value of iv, key and encrypted data is exactly same in both scenarios.

Comment: Did you try to first encrypt something and see if it generates the same ciphertext? "Known-answer tests" tend to help identify the issue. If you would have a value for which you know what it should decrypt to you might see what the issue is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `decrypt` takes two slightly different meanings:

- In WebCrypto, `decrypt` is a once-off operation that performs decryption **and** verification of the MAC tag. The tag is assumed to be the last 16 bytes of the input. You can call `decrypt` only once. In some APIs, this method is (better) called `unseal` or `unbox`, to highlight that it does more than decrypting data.
- In PyCryptodome, `decrypt` is a *streaming* operation that  decrypts **all the data** you provide. You can call `decrypt` multiple times (hence, it is useful in a streaming context where you process a chunk at a time). There is a separate `verify` method to check the MAC tag at the very end. The once-off method `decrypt_and_verify` is the equivalent of `decrypt` in WebCrypto world.

You should therefore modify your Python code:

```
res = cipher_item_key.decrypt(unhexlify(encrypted_data))
```

To be:

```
raw = unhexlify(encrypted_data)
res = cipher_item_key.decrypt_and_verify(raw[:-16], raw[-16:])
```

---

Similarly for encryption:

- In WebCrypto, `encrypt` performs two operations: actual encryption but also creation of the MAC tag. The output consists of ciphertext and the 16-byte tag, concatenated. You can call `encrypt` only once.
- In PyCryptodome, `encrypt` only performs encryption and you must call `digest` at the very end (possibly after multiple `encrypt` calls) to get the 16-byte MAC tag. The method that performs encryption and creation of the MAC tag is actually `encrypt_and_digest` (same as `decrypt` in WebCrypto).

It is also helpful to look at the state machine of an AEAD modes (like GCM is) in PyCryptodome:

[image]

Comment: Can you also please answer the `encryption part`. I added it as a separate question earlier but it got marked as duplicate and I've merged it into this question now.

Comment: I'm facing a different issue with encryption. I'm already using `encrypt_and_digest` and the output does not match at all.

Comment: That's because you are not encrypting the same data. In the JS case, your string gets encoded as UTF-16, in the Python case it's ASCII.